# pie chart in php with mysql data using chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, chart.js

I wish to add  pie chart using charts.js in my project.
I searched and found some code for simple chart. 
Part of my code for chart is below:

```
printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/Chart.js"></script>' );
printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/jquery-min.js"></script>' );
printf( '<p style="text-align: center;">' );
printf( '<canvas id="mycanvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>' );
printf( '<script type="text/javascript">' );
 ?>
    var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var piedata = [
    {
    value:30,
    color:"green",
    label:"sta1",
    labelColor : 'white'
    },
    {
    value:60,
    color:"red",
    label:"sta1",
    labelColor : 'white'
    },
    {
    value:50,
    color:"blue"
    }
    ]

    new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);
    <?php
    printf( '</script>' );
```

What can I do for dynamic chart.That is the value should come from MySQL DB.
Number of data value from DB will differ every time.Each data value has specific colors.

With the above code the label is not visible explicitly(only on mouse over).

Please suggest me the way.

Comment: not relevant to highcharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your data coming from json response and push the data in an Array

```
var piedata = [];
$.each(yourJson,function(i,val){
piedata.push({value:val.value,color:val.color,label:val.label,labelColor:val.labelColor  });
});
```

and then set new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);

Comment: Thanks for the reply.can you tell me how to display legend for this chart?

Comment: It would be nice if you can create a fiddle of your problem. while on documentation legends for pie charts are as legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

Comment: I have tried your code.But how can I set color for values since database does not have.We have to set colors for each values manually.is there any way?

Comment: if you want to set random colors use following code while populating your array  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
   
    color = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')'; and push this color in your array

Comment: see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ww6tzt3s/6/

Comment: @Nithya.K were you able to get that?

Comment: @  Nishith Chaturvedi I got pie chart.can you tell me about drawing multiple pie charts in a single page with the code you suggested above?

Comment: you have to invoke chart in conatiner like mycanvas in a loop. Paste your actual sql query response here.

Comment: Do you mean the 'mycanvas' tag and sql query will go in a loop?.

Comment: I have created a fiddle with multiple pie, http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/NXPhL/1807/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/NXPhL/1808/

Comment: I got your example on fiddle.This is only for 2 pie.In case 2 or more than pie is there or we dont know the exact count of pie(if that info is from DB) ,then what is the possible way?..Can you share your thoughts?

Comment: @Nithya.K its simple , call your api and check length of object. create  canvas with "someClass" dynamically

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/NXPhL/1809/ I created dynamically